Time clauses with different tenses
I know that we don't use future tenses after time clauses.

I will do it when you will come

That's why sentence number 1 is wrong
What about present continuous and be going to

I will do it when you are coming

I will do it when you are going to come


How about 2 and 3?

#3 is unlikely, but it's possible to imagine contexts where it's quite natural (speaker assumes that at some point in the future, addressee will decide to come, so it's possible to refer to that future time). But #2 is incredibly unlikely - almost certainly the only credible phrasing would be I will do it while you are coming (but normally we'd say something like while you are on your way here). We normally just use Simple Present for contexts like X will happen when Y happens.

"I'll bake a cake when you're coming for tea" (assuming that the addressee will accept an invitation at some time in the future). Not a very likely combination of tenses.
